# Adding/Removing labels of line points with update

Tags: d3.js, label

I'm using a range slider to add/remove points from a line which follows an histogram.
Without updating the data, the text labels are shown correctly, when I update the values with the slider I'd like that the text-labels follow the line, so they show the values of the points correctly.
The update for the line works, but I am not able to update the text labels correctly.

Right now the laberls are plotted like so outside of the on-change function:

```
var SerifText = svg.append("g")
    .attr("id", "serif-labels")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(histogSerif)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function (d) { return d.y >= 1 ? d.y : null; })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", 10 + "px")
    .attr("fill", "#f0027f")
    .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.x)})
    .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.y) - padding; })
    .attr("visibility", "hidden"); //the hidden & visible is managed by an external checkbox
```

And then on the on-change function I put this code:

```
    SerifText.selectAll("text").remove(); 
    /* If I do SerifText.remove() it does remove the text but also the group of course, 
but as it is it doesn't work */
    SerifText.selectAll("text")
        .data(histogSerif)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text(function (d) { return d.y >= 1 ? d.y : null; })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-size", 10 + "px")
        .attr("fill", "#f0027f")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.x)})
        .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.y) - padding; });
```

But this doesn't work unfortunately. I'd like also to be able to retain the manage of the visible/hidden status by the external checkbox if possible.
Full code is [here](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37967455/confronto_pesi.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to save a reference to the labels that you are going to delete, and then re-selecting them, how about just use a variable that references the SerifText  element selection, e.g.:

```
var SerifTextGroup = svg.append("g")
            .attr("id", "serif-labels");  

SerifTextGroup.selectAll("text")
            .data(histogSerif)
            .enter()
            //... and so on
```

Then the rest of your code should work as written (just change `SerifText` to `SerifTextGroup`).

Comment: I already tried that but probably I did something wrong, because I tried it again and it worked this time, thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it -- It's a neat graphic!

Comment: Thanks, it's going to be part of my thesis so I'm glad to hear it